# Three.js rendering in white fog on chrome after new update

Tags: javascript, three.js

I opened the browser yesterday and all of my three.js projects are rendered with little or no color, in a white fog. I checked the Three.js website and noticed that some of their examples are also rendered this way. This happens only on Chrome browser, Safari and Firefox are ok. Both use webGL renderer.

Update: I checked on linux  and windows, apparently the problem is only on Mac, I'm using OS X YOSEMITE 10.10.5

**Solution:** Apparently it was a problem with alpha, i noticed that all projects that have white fog have setClearColor() function, after changing the renderer alpha:true the fog disappeared

[Link to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpQtR.png)

[My Project](http://after.haus)

Comment: Using Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m on Win7, your website looks exactly like it should.

Comment: I checked on linux and windows, apparently the problem is only on Mac

Comment: I might also be specific to the video card / graphics driver.

Comment: Looks fine on my macbook pro. Try the site in  yourSafari/Firefox too. Otherwise It looks like your gamma got boosted somehow. Worth a Try... go to System Settings, Display, Color tab, "Calibrate..." and go through the calibration module. Sorry looks lie you checked safari and firefox. Try the calibration anyhow.

Comment: @VasilieMilenkovic See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9685